# Symfony randomly crash - DebugClassLoader.php

Tags: php, apache, symfony, caching

I have site based on symfony framework but on develop enviroment i have random crashes with exception: (with bad characters)

> Warning: class_implements(): Class 
>   ���� does not exist and could not be loaded

or

> Warning: class_implements(): Class H�d 
>   ���� does not exist and could not be loaded

or

> ContextErrorException in DebugClassLoader.php line 203: 
>  Warning: class_implements(): Class multipart/form-data does not exist and could not be loaded

(php is not using symfony forms and request is GET)

or

> OutOfMemoryException in DebugClassLoader.php line 203: 
> Error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 1141972672 bytes)

(Memory limit is set on 128MB but for request is needed approximately 6MB)

All this different exceptions was thrown on one url with same parameter (for the testing purpose) so they are throwing randomly through whole web.

This bugs **aren't on production** enviroment **only develop**.

Develop enviroment is on windows 7 machine with XAMPP/apache.

*If i restrat apache and press F5 everything is ok and web working ok.*

I was trying clear all caches but without success.

Any ideas?

EDIT:

---

**After activate OPCache** the problem persists...

My config from symfony debug bar:
[image]

If i run command `php bin/symfony_requirements` from CLI

```
> PHP is using the following php.ini file:
  C:\xampp7.0.9\php\php.ini

> Checking Symfony requirements:
  ...........................WW.......


 [OK]
 Your system is ready to run Symfony projects


Optional recommendations to improve your setup
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

 * intl extension should be available
   > Install and enable the intl extension (used for validators).

 * a PHP accelerator should be installed
   > Install and/or enable a PHP accelerator (highly recommended).


Note  The command console could use a different php.ini file
~~~~  than the one used with your web server. To be on the
      safe side, please check the requirements from your web
      server using the web/config.php script.
```

Comment: Do you use APC ?

Comment: I was updated my question - as you can see on pic - no i am not using APC.

Comment: Think the windows come from windows. But you should have at least an accelerator enabled. Try to launch : `php bin/symfony_requirements` at the root of your project in CLI to see if there are errors reported.

Comment: Question updated

Comment: Try to activate opcache, this is the way to go with PHP7.

Comment: I was activate OPCache but still same problem.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem with "Warning: class_implements(): Class ���� does not exist and could not be loaded"

I increased realpath_cache_size in php.ini and now apache works, no errors.

Comment: How value you have? I was increase it but today it crash again. So i doubled it to 2048k. Will see

Comment: I set realpath_cache_size = 64M

Comment: hi I just had the same problem and in my case `realpath_cache_size` was not even set (it was commented) in *php.ini*, I just *uncommented* it and left the default value, in this case **4096k**. The weird thing is this was out of the blue, never had happened before, it's like it was having a bad day or something :). Were you able to investigate further in the matter and find out what went wrong?

Comment: I have the same issue in prestashop. Fixed it by increasing cache size. realpath_cache_size